# How to rewrite $e^{-x} = -\ln(x)$ such that the Lambert W function can be applied?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, lambert-w

Original problem:
Find the real solution of $$e^{-x} = -\ln(x)$$
The first thing I did was divide both sides by $e^{-x}$.
With a few more steps I arrived at
$$e^x\ln(x) = -1$$
This was great, but still not a solution. I checked Wolfram|Alpha to see what the solution was, and it said that that $x$ was $W(1)$, or alternatively $e^{-W(1)}$.

I'm just wondering, what are the steps you need to make to get to the answer of $W(1)$?

Comment: I think this is not correct, can you share the query you did on WA?

Comment: I queried "e^-x = -ln(x)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^{-x}=-\ln(x)$$

We want to solve the equation in terms of Lambert W. We therefore try to bring the equation to a form $te^t=\text{constant}$:

$x\to e^t$:
$$e^{-e^t}=-t$$
But we see we cannot achieve this goal.

To be able to apply Lambert W anyway, we try to bring at least one side of the equation to a form $f(x)e^{f(x)}$:

$$-xe^{-x}=x\ln(x)$$
$$-x=W(x\ln(x))$$
$$-x=\ln(x)$$
$x\to e^t$:
$$-e^t=t$$
$$-1=te^{-t}$$
$$1=-te^{-t}$$
$$-te^{-t}=1$$
$$-t=W(1)$$
$$t=-W(1)$$
$$x=e^{-W(1)}$$
$$x=W(1)$$

Answer (score 3):

let $w=W(1)$.  Then, by definition, we have $we^w=1$.

It follows that $e^{-w}=w$ and, taking logs, we also have $w=-\ln(w)$.  Combining these we see that $$e^{-w}=-\ln w$$ as desired.

Not sure that this generalizes in any particularly useful way....

Answer (score 0):

$-\log(x)$ is the symmetric function of $e^{-x}$ rotated around the symmetry axis $x=y$ (i.e. the 45-degree axis). Therefore they both will intersect at a point $x_0$ along the symmetry axis where $x=y$. Thus both $e^{-x_0}=x_0=-\log(x_0)$. The function $w\cdot e^{w}=z$ is involved in the definition of the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) with $w=W_k(z)$. Therefore for $z=1$ we have $e^{-w}=w$, in which $w=W(1)$.